# "BluePill" STM32F103 плохо работает с Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-ide

Есть отладочная плата на микроконтроллере STM32F103. Задача - сделать так, чтобы эта плата прошивалась по USB в Arduino IDE.

Для этого я устанавливаю перемычки [Boot0:1; Boot1:0], с помощью USB-UART преобразователя через FlashLoaderDemonstrator заливаю прошивку generic_boot20_pc13.bin.

Ставлю перемычки в положение [0; 0], подключаю плату по USB к компьютеру, она определяется как Maple Serial (все хорошо).

Заливаю любой скетч - с этого момента плата определяется только как Maple DFU, виртуальный COM-порт не создается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать, чтобы прошивку через COM-порт можно было загрузить неограниченное количество раз? Ранее сталкивался с такими платами, все работало, в чем проблема сейчас - не знаю.